# Is there a brunch equivalent to browserify's paths

Tags: brunch

In Browserify, I can use the `paths` option to avoid doing things like `require('../../../lib/foo')`. Is there a way to do this with Brunch?

Here's an example of the browserify option:

```
var b = browserify({
    paths: [
      './gulp/assets/javascripts'
    ]
  })
```

If I had a `./gulp/assets/javascripts/lib` folder, using the browserify configuration above, I could just `require('lib/foo')` anywhere in my project, and it'll work.

Comment: this is the default behavior for anything in the `app` folder but I can't find where this can be customized in the [config](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md)

Comment: @maxlath That's good to know! Unfortunately, I'm integrating into a Rails app, so I don't have an `app` folder.